# Migrating from requirejs to es6 imports

Tags: javascript, require, es6-modules

I have a javascript app that uses requireJS to load its components. This is simple example of how it works:

```
require(['eventHandler'], function(eventHandler)) {
    ... // app code that uses the eventHandler in some way
}
```

It uses several components, but let's simplify it and pretend its only this one.

I have two different "versions" of my miniapp in 2 parts of the bigger web application we develop in my company. In order to improve reusability I came up with the following idea:

I have 2 files of require configuration that define the location of the modules the app needs to run and I can define the set of components it should use for each case.

Standard config:

```
require.config({
paths : {
    // components
    eventHandler : 'lib/eventHandlers/standardEventHandler',
    ...
});
```

Especial config:

```
require.config({
paths : {
    // components
    eventHandler : 'lib/eventHandlers/specialEventHandler',
    ...
});
```

When I load the app I do the following:

```
 <script data-main="@standardConfigFile" src="/lib/require/require.js"
        type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

And this is how I can load different components for each configuration. Currently I have 2 different ones but I expect to increase that number soon.

Now we are switching to es6 modules with native import and export and I wonder how can I migrate my current architecture to native js imports and exports and the documentation does not cover this particular problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: One of the biggest things that you are going to need to address is the fact that ES6 imports (for right now) are synchronous which is in constrast to the asynchronous module definition (AMD) that require.js follows.  Do you want to retain the asynchronousness of your library imports?  Do you want to incorporate the async proposal for ES6?  You can read a little about that distinction here: [ES proposal: import() – dynamically importing ES modules](http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html).

Comment: Could you pass an environment variable as part of your build process and use that to drive which import you are grabbing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it's actually really simple. I only need to make an "importer" module.

In my main component I'll do:

```
import * as components from '@standardComponentsLoader.js';
```

And then do all the imports in standardComponentsLoader:

```
import * as eventHandler from '@standardEventHandler.js';

export { eventHandler };
```